# Include an XML file in the Project Build

Tags: vb.net

I have written a small VB.NET simulation program that uses an XML file to configure the simulation.  I want to include this file in the project build so that when the application is installed, there will be a default XML file in the required directory.

When I do the Project Publish (within VB 2010 Express), there is no option for including any extra data files in the process.

Is it possible to do this with VB 2010 Express ... or should I try some other project builder/installer.

Any pointers will be very much appreciated,

Regards,

Oliver

Answer (score 5):

The option isn’t found in the publisher, it’s a property of the file itself: when you add a file to the project you can set its [file properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66.aspx) in the property window (usually at the right-hand side of the screen, below the file browser).

There you can set its “**Build Action**” to “**Content**” and its “**Copy to Output Directory**” mode to “**Copy if newer**”.

Comment: Oh dear, I must have set up everything wrong.  I simply hardcoded the file path into the program.

Comment: Back to the dreawing board, will look at adding the file to the project.  Thanks for the very quick response, very much appreciated.

Comment: Had a go and no luck, so will log another question specifically to the problem that has now arisen.  Thanks for the pointer